# Fazer altura da div diminuir conforme usuário diminuir tela

Tags: jquery

Tenho um div e quero que ela diminua quando o usuário diminuir a tela. Tenho algo parecido com a largura, que fiz assim: `($(window).width() -320)` ele pega a largura total da tela e diminui 320px. Com a altura eu não sei fazer.

Alguém já fez isso?

Por exemplo, tenho a div `fundo1` e quando o usuário diminuir a janela, pelo próprio navegador, a div diminua também.

Comment: Você quer fazer um layout recursivo certo? Já tentou usar o bootstrap ? Com fica muito mais fácil fazer essas coisas com as classes dele.

Comment: Use um sistema de grids, como 960.gs ou twitter bootstrap...

Comment: O site já está todo pronto :) Só foi requisitado eu fazer essa div diminuir após eu ter terminado. Ou seja, não usarei Bootstrap. Procuro algo em Jquery mesmo, só que está me faltando o conhecimento necessário agora.

Comment: Dá pra fazer com `height` relativo, via CSS mesmo:

Comment: @Beterraba como? Estava tentando `function resizeFundo1(){
    var telaAltura = $(window).height();
    $('.fundo1img').css({'height': telaAltura + 'px'});
}` mas não rolou

Comment: Se você setar sua div com altura relativa (`height: 90%`, por exemplo), ela vai ocupar 90% da altura definida no pai dela.

Comment: @Beterraba mas não é isso que preciso. Eu preciso que `div` diminua conforme o usuário movimentar o tamanho da tela.

Comment: Veja [este fiddle](http://jsbin.com/zekibulo/1).

Comment: Valeu @Beterraba

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode dar uma olhada no evento `$.resize` (http://api.jquery.com/resize/) do Jquery

Aqui está um exemplo que fiz para você ver como funciona

*JQuery*

```
$(function(){
    $(window).resize(function(){
        var winW = $(window).width();
        var winH = $(window).height();
        var divResize = $(".divResize");

        if(winW < 500)
            divResize.css('width', winW);
        if(winH < 500)
            divResize.css('height', winH);
    });
});
```

*HTML*

```
<div class="divResize"></div>
```

*CSS*

```
body, html {
    height:100%;
    min-height:100%;
    padding:0;
}

.divResize {
    background:#000;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    max-width:500px;
    max-height:500px;
}
```

Nesse exemplo quando a área útil do navegador for menor que 500px ele irá dar um resize de acordo com o tamanho da tela.

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/dieegov/55APa/)**

Caso essa sua `div` seja um background e ocupa 100% (tanto largura como altura), há algumas dicas que você poderá estar utilizando.

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/dieegov/z7ypM/)**